# What happens when the Crown loses their Stead?

Tags: powered-by-the-apocalypse, scup

There is a number of characters across The Sword, The Crown and The Unspeakable Power who are defined strongly by the resources they control. The Crown rules over a Stead, The Spur commands a Militia, The Beloved leads Followers. However, in PbtA's outlook of narrative first it is conceivable that these characters could lose their resource - not just have it reduced to the bare minimum or stripped of usefulness. I'm talking about a situation where a ruler (The Crown) gets dethroned or a general (The Spur) is dismissed. What then? Gut feeling suggests the associated moves should become unavailable, but does a situation like that mandate a character reroll?

The question is specific to SCUP, but in AW the Hardholder or the Chopper are in a similar situation.

Answer (score 4):

## "On our next exciting episode..."

One of the SCUP guiding principles is still "be a fan of the PCs", and here's some AW advice about that:

> The worst way there is to make a character’s life more interesting is to take away the things that made the character cool to begin with. The gunlugger’s guns, but also the gunlugger’s collection of ancient photographs — what makes the character match our expectations and also what makes the character rise above them. Don’t take those away.

"Take away" here is in the sense of "permanently".

Of course the Crown might be deposed, their session-opener Stead move makes allowance for when their rule is insecure or challenged. A Spur with no army, or a Beloved with the followers move and no followers, doesn't have that kind of fallback - but of course any move for dealing with those groups is going to rely on the character in the fiction doing something with their subordinates, and if they don't have any, that fiction can't happen.

But more importantly than that, someone whose playbook or moves gives them a holding, gang, or followers (or their SCUP equivalents) is entitled to, responsible for, and interesting at least in part because of them. If you spin up a plot to take those things away, you'd also better have a followup waiting in the wings where they can get them back or die trying. (In the case of a gang or followers, maybe "get them back" becomes "find a new batch of rowdies/believers to lead".)

I mean, unless it's a giant transformative end-of-season thing and when some Sea Hag pulls the Crown's entire Stead into a destructive vortex, they come back next season as a Gauntlet sworn to revenge. That's also pretty cool.

Answer (score 2):

### You and what army?

In all PbtA games, moves are triggered by the fiction. So if the fiction involves the absence of something that is required for the move to trigger, then the move does not trigger at all. Yeah, sometimes that sucks. But there's still a lot to go around with the basic moves.

In case a player insists, do ask them how. Maybe they can come up with a plausible story to trigger their favourite move. If they do it, they do it. To do it, they must do it.

In other words, nothing special happens. Just keep playing as usual.

Comment: Disclaimer: I have no experience with SCUP. All I have is the catch-all PbtA perspective.

Answer (score 2):

SCUP intentionally plays towards stories like *A Song of Ice and Fire* and *The First Law*. A fictional response to a deposed Crown or a crushed Spur might very well be their death. It doesn't have to be death, but give the player the option. Also consider changing the character's class or making a new character instead.

That said, a surviving Crown or Spur might still have a band of devoted and loyal followers, whatever's left over from their fall. It makes sense in the fiction to change up the Stead and Militia's tags and, likely, their character's Look. They are likely in a bad spot.